# How to speed up denormalized table with indexes

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have created a denormalized table which has 35 columns and 360k records. the table consist of 8 other tables. Table only has one inner join with some other table.

My main problem is performance, queries to this table works so slow. I also have full-text catalog related to that table. Fts searches also slow.
Also i am having deadlocks, in activity monitor i see LCK_IM_X, LCK_IM_S wait types.

I placed indexes like crazy and followed query executions plans. 
Now i know that table scan is bad when there's too much record. I passed that long time ago, but right now, Index Scan's are going with %80 cost.

In below, inside of select comes from another table as string, this query works very much at its top speed. Also, i dynamically build where clause along with other conditions.
[image: a busy cat]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQ3mi.jpg

```
SET @Sql=';WITH TempResult AS(Select '+(SELECT STUFF((SELECT ',' +DBFieldName FROM TableFields where TableFields.TableID=3 FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, ''))+',
0 as [DeviceChange],
0 as [DeviceReturn],
0 as [SNORepeat]
 from DenormalizedTable
inner join Companies On Companies.CompanyID=DenormalizedTable.CompanyID
WHERE  (@state is null or DenormalizedTable.StateID=@state) 
            AND ((@status = -1 AND DenormalizedTable.Status IN(0,1,10,11,4)) OR (@status=1 AND DenormalizedTable.Status IN(1,4,10,11)) OR
             (@status=2 AND DenormalizedTable.Status IN (0))) AND (@CategoryID is null or DenormalizedTable.CategoryID=@CategoryID)
             AND (DenormalizedTable.CompanyID=@companyID OR Companies.SubCompanyOf=@companyID)
                 '+ ( CASE WHEN @CustomSearchParam='' THEN '' ELSE (Select dbo.[perf_whereBuilder](@CustomSearchParam)) END)+'
             AND (@technicianID is null or DenormalizedTable.JobOrderID IN (Select AttendedStaff.JobOrderID from AttendedStaff Where AttendedStaff.StaffID=@technicianID))
             AND (@FilterStartDate is null or convert(varchar, JobOrder_PerfTable.StartDate, 20) between @FilterStartDate and @FilterEndDate) 
), TotalCount AS (Select COUNT(*) as TotalCount from TempResult)

        Select * from TempResult, TotalCount 
          order by 1  desc 

            OFFSET     @skip ROWS      
FETCH NEXT @take ROWS ONLY;';
```

when i run the sp it tooks almos 5 seconds to load. if there's any search parameter it goes even more.

I need to know what i should do to run query faster, sorry if question is broad.

Comment: You have quite a few scans there; you need to start looking there. Most likely you don't have any covering indexes to help the data engine. On a different note, you really want to ensure you quote your dynamic objects with SQL like this to avoid injection and/or unexpected behaviour (for example when a column has a name that has to be delimit identified).

Comment: Well, i placed many indexes on the table by order of usage. i even tried to put non-clustered index on every column. but no luck, engine still using the high costl ones. I also discovered using too much index is also bad. Dynamic query is another story :( ..

Comment: Yes, having too many index is a problem, and having loads of indexes only referencing 1 column won't help here. We really need the DDL of your tables, and the respective index, along with the SQL that is executed (not the statement that generates the dynamic statement).